# Can initialising a thread in a class constructor lead to a crash?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl

I have not been able to determine where a strange crash is coming from, but the fact it's not happening deterministically makes me suspect threading.

I have something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
 MyClass() : mExit(false), mThread(&MyClass::ThreadMain,this)
 {}

 void ThreadMain()
 {
  unique_lock<mutex> lock(mMutex);
  mCondition.wait(lock, [&] { return mExit; });
 }

 std::thread mThread;
 std::mutex mMutex;
 std::condition_variable mCondition;
 bool mExit;
};
```

Obviously this is very simplified but I don't know for sure where the crash is happening yet so I want to ask if this setup *can* cause issues? What order is everything initialised for instance - is there a possibility `ThreadMain` can run before an instance of the class is fully constructed for example?

It looks like some examples I've seen online but I am not certain enough to say it's definitely safe or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only issue I see is that class members are initialized in the order they are declared in the class.  Since `mThread` comes before all of the other class members it could be possible that the thread is using them before they are ever initialized.

To fix this you can rearrange the class members but I do not like this approach.  If someone else comes along and changes the order it could break the code.  You should be able to let the thread get default initialized and then start the thread in the constructor body because at that point all class members have been initialized.

Comment: I didn't realise `mutex` and `condition_variable` _needed_ initialising? Or are you saying I should explicitly do so e.g. : `MyClass() : mExit(false), mMutex(), mCondition(), mThread(&MyClass::ThreadMain,this)`

Comment: @Mr.Boy I would never use an uninitialized variable so yes I would default initialize them in the constructor.

Comment: @NathanOliver Not including _objects_ in the initialization list will cause them to be _default initialized_. Including them in the initializer list, passing zero arguments to the constructor, will cause the objects to be _value initialized_.

Comment: @NathanOliver But the members are initialized, just not explicitly. In this case, initializing them explicitly might have given a hint of the problem, but only maybe, and in general, I feel explicitly default-initializing non-primitives is a waste of space.

Comment: I think I can pin this as the cause of my problem... not initialising the thread in the init-list but in the ctor body fixed my issues. Not sure whether to put an answer or ask @NathanOliver to add that to his answer as an alternative, and accept it? But the short answer is: YES

Comment: @Mr.Boy Added to the answer to explain the fixes.  If you want to accept this answer that is your choice.  If you want to post your own detailing what you did fell free.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the member-construction-order-vs-thread-early-execution issue described by [@NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33571990/873025), I would like to point out that the code will still exhibit undefined behaviour when using a virtual fuction in the place of `ThreadMain`.

Using a virtual function with your design is a problem as virtual functions are looked up from the vtable, and the pointer to the vtable isn't initialized until the constructor block has finished executing. Thus you end up with a thread that uses a pointer to a function that isn't initialized yet, which is UB.

The general solution to this kind of RAII thread-handler problem is to separate the initialization of the object from the execution of the thread, *e.g.*, using a `start` function. This will also remove the dependency on the construction order of the members.

```
struct MyClass {
    MyClass() : mExit(false) {}
    void start() { mThread = std::thread{&ThreadMain, this}; } // Start function.
    virtual void ThreadMain() = 0;

    std::atomic<bool> mExit; // Not even bool is atomic :)
    std::mutex mMutex;
    std::condition_variable mCondition;
    std::thread mThread;
};
```

This ensures that `MyClass` is constructed when starting the thread. Now, it is also possible to use polymorphism.

```
struct Derived : public MyClass {
    virtual void ThreadMain() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mMutex);
        mCondition.wait(lock, [&] { return mExit.load(); });
    }
};
```

However, now the thread must be started using two statements instead of one, *e.g.*, `MyClass m; m.start();`. To get around this we can simply create a wrapper class that executes the `start` function in the constructor body.

```
struct ThreadHandler {
    ThreadHandler() { d.start(); }
    Derived d;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it could have bad behaviour since `mThread` may be started while the `MyClass` instance is not yet constructed.

My thumb rule: if I have to use `this` in the constructor, I doing something naughty ;).